# Convert GeoPackage to GeoJSON with ogr2ogr not working

Tags: ogr2ogr

The command

```bash
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON out.json BGRI2021_0706.gpkg
```

returns

```
ERROR 1: database disk image is malformed
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `BGRI2021_0706.gpkg' with the following drivers.
  -> `FITS'
  -> `PCIDSK'
  -> `netCDF'
  -> `PDS4'
  -> `VICAR'
  -> `JP2OpenJPEG'
  -> `PDF'
  -> `MBTiles'
  -> `BAG'
  -> `EEDA'
  -> `OGCAPI'
  -> `ESRI Shapefile'
  -> `MapInfo File'
  -> `UK .NTF'
  -> `LVBAG'
  -> `OGR_SDTS'
  -> `S57'
  -> `DGN'
  -> `OGR_VRT'
  -> `REC'
  -> `Memory'
  -> `CSV'
  -> `NAS'
  -> `GML'
  -> `GPX'
  -> `LIBKML'
  -> `KML'
  -> `GeoJSON'
  -> `GeoJSONSeq'
  -> `ESRIJSON'
  -> `TopoJSON'
  -> `Interlis 1'
  -> `Interlis 2'
  -> `OGR_GMT'
  -> `GPKG'
  -> `SQLite'
  -> `ODBC'
  -> `WAsP'
  -> `PGeo'
  -> `MSSQLSpatial'
  -> `OGR_OGDI'
  -> `PostgreSQL'
  -> `MySQL'
  -> `OpenFileGDB'
  -> `DXF'
  -> `CAD'
  -> `FlatGeobuf'
  -> `Geoconcept'
  -> `GeoRSS'
  -> `GPSTrackMaker'
  -> `VFK'
  -> `PGDUMP'
  -> `OSM'
  -> `GPSBabel'
  -> `OGR_PDS'
  -> `WFS'
  -> `OAPIF'
  -> `SOSI'
  -> `Geomedia'
  -> `EDIGEO'
  -> `SVG'
  -> `CouchDB'
  -> `Cloudant'
  -> `Idrisi'
  -> `ARCGEN'
  -> `XLS'
  -> `ODS'
  -> `XLSX'
  -> `Elasticsearch'
  -> `Walk'
  -> `Carto'
  -> `AmigoCloud'
  -> `SXF'
  -> `Selafin'
  -> `JML'
  -> `PLSCENES'
  -> `CSW'
  -> `VDV'
  -> `GMLAS'
  -> `MVT'
  -> `NGW'
  -> `MapML'
  -> `TIGER'
  -> `AVCBin'
  -> `AVCE00'
  -> `HTTP'
```

I am in the correct directory and the file exists

```bash
ll BGRI2021_0706.gpkg  -h
-rw-r--r-- 1 joao joao 1,1M nov 28 18:07 BGRI2021_0706.gpkg
```

ogr2ogr support the format:

```bash
$ ogrinfo --formats | grep GPKG
  GPKG -raster,vector- (rw+vs): GeoPackage
```

I am using v3.3.2

```bash
$ ogr2ogr --version
GDAL 3.3.2, released 2021/09/01
```